# Visual Studio Code, pointing to a component in another directory

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

My problem I believe is with VSCode. I am using Angular 2 with TypeScript but I don't think that the problem lies there. I am trying to import a class from another directory and I get an error on this line.

```
import {Employee} from '../models/employee.model'
```

and here is a screenshot of my directory tree.

[image]

Comment: what is your code for employee.model.ts? and which folder did you try to import ? give an example please.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The error says "[ts] Cannot find module ../models/employee.model @brando

Comment: and this is what I have in my Employee.ts file @Majid export class      Employee{
    constructor(
        public FirstName: string,
        public LastName: string
    ){}
}

Answer (score 0):

Is it compile time or run time error. if it is compile time, then better to check the path that file reside. if it is runtime check with Webpack config, what includes in dist.

Comment: The error says "[ts] Cannot find module ../models/employee.model"

Comment: '../models/employee.model' maybe this is wrong, copy the employee.ts to the folder or check do you have the export statement in employee.ts class